# Parsing SVG - transformation matrix decomposition

Tags: matrix, svg, transformation, decomposition

I need to parse SVG (just the simples things) and only thing left to do is to properly extract position and angle from the matrix transformation. I know this question has been asked many times and I believe I have went through many of the answers, documents etc. but still cannot handle it proporly. Here's the simplest example I managed to prepare:

I have created 1000x1000 document (all numbers in px) and put a rectangle of 100x100 size at 100,100 position. It has generated the following piece of SVG file (I have removed style attrib. and parent tags). There's no other transformation anywhere in the file:

```
    <rect
       width="100"
       height="100"
       x="100"
       y="100" />
```

Then I have rotated the rectangle by 33deg (with the 'transform' inkscape tool). The SVG code looks this:

```
   <rect
       width="100"
       height="100"
       x="-5.8952699"
       y="157.49644"
       transform="matrix(0.83867057,-0.54463904,0.54463904,0.83867057,0,0)" />
```

Now, my goal is to extract the position and angle from the matrix, so basically I'd like to get back the following values: x:100,y:100,angle:33. In order to do it, I have assumed the following formulas:

```
sx=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
sy=sqrt(c^2+d^2)

t=atan(c/d) OR t=atan(-b/a)
t=acos(a) if MATRIX is PURE

x' = tx + sx*(COS(t)*x-SIN(t)*y)
y' = ty + sy*(SIN(t)*x+COS(t)*y)
```

the result is:
t = 0.575958787 (which is 33deg) - PERFECTLY FINE

however
x'=-90.72230563 and y'=128.8770646
and this is exactly what totally confuses me - why it's not 100,100 ?

Comment: About what centre did you rotate the square in Inkscape?  Also, can you clarify what `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `tx`, `ty`, `x` and `y`  are in your calculations?

Comment: OK, it seems the rotation is about the centre of the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can find out the coordinates.  I'm using Python for my calculations here.

The matrix transform is applied with the centre of rotation being (0, 0).  The coordinates (-5.895, 157.496) are where the square will need to be so that if you rotate the rectangle 33 degrees with the centre of rotation at (0, 0), it will end up rotated 33 degrees about its centre.

First, it seems you don't have a problem figuring out the angle of rotation.  We'll just concentrate on how to figure out the position.

Let's start with what we know:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> c = math.cos(33 * math.pi / 180)
>>> s = math.sin(33 * math.pi / 180)
>>> c
0.838670567945424
>>> s
0.5446390350150271
>>> x0 = -5.8952699
>>> y0 = 157.49644
```

These are the coordinates of the top-left corner of the square, before it has been rotated.  The square is rotated about its centre, and we want to find out where its centre is rotated to:

```
>>> x1 = x0 + 50
>>> y1 = y0 + 50
>>> x1
44.1047301
>>> y1
207.49644
```

Now, rotate the centre of the square:

```
>>> x2 = c * x1 + s * y1
>>> y2 = -s * x1 + c * y1
>>> x2
149.9999998927001
>>> y2
149.9999995401914
```

It's clear from here how we get to where the top-left corner of the square would be if the square wasn't rotated.

```
>>> x3 = x2 - 50
>>> y3 = y2 - 50
>>> x3
99.99999989270009
>>> y3
99.9999995401914
```

Comment: @user2273369: glad to hear my answer helped.  Hopefully you didn't copy it too closely; there was an error in the calculation of x3, which should have been calculated from x2, not y2.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: It's OK - I didn't notice this flaw. Works great!

Comment: Hey, once again :) Looks like the algorythm doesn work for following matrix: 0,1,-1,0,0,0. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2273369: I've no idea why, and by not giving any information about what actually happened and what should have happened, you're not making it easy to find out why.  A matrix of 0,1,-1,0,0,0 is a 90-degree rotation, one way or the other.

Comment: You are right, I was not descriptive enough this time - I apologize. I will prepare a numbers-based example and post here soon. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: OK, here's the deal: I have created a square 100x100 and placed it at position of x=100,y=100. Then, I have rotated the square by -90deg and it produced the following results:
matrix:0,1,-1,0,0,0
x:100
y:-200

Now, when I follow the calculation you have provided earlier the final x3=-200 and y3=-200 which is wrong since it should be 100,100.

Those formulas though works ok for all the other rotations I've tried and they also work fine for +90deg rotation.

Do you know where's the issue?

Comment: Oh I am thinking right now maybe your formulas are ok and the issue is I am calculating the rotation wrongly: since it's PURE matrix I just do acos(a) and it gives me 90, instead of -90.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed - rotation is wrong. When it's -90, the final x3,y3 works good. How should I calculate the rotation in this case?